# facebook image uploading issue iphone

Tags: iphone

I have implemented facebook in my application , In which I am successfully uploading image over facebook wall .
But sometime if any user deletes image from facebook wall (Remove this post or remove image with app name) , then it sometimes hide image from facebook wall.
If I check code of application for uploding image I am getting id of uploding image .
But still the image is not getting displayed on the wall of the facebook.

Had anybody faced similar sort of issue with Facebook Graph API.

Also it is uploading fine with some accounts but facing issue with others.

Following is the code snippet of what I am doing to post image

```
NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];
if(image != nil )
{
    @try 
{
FbGraphFile *graph_file = [[FbGraphFile alloc] initWithImage:image];
[variables setObject:graph_file forKey:@"file"];
[variables setObject:feedText forKey:@"message"];
FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/photos" withPostVars:variables];
NSLog(@"postPictureButtonandmessgaePressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);
NSString *tempMssg=NSLocalizedString(@"Image Successfully Post",@"Alert Facebook Success");
UIAlertView *alt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:tempMssg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alt show];
[alt release];
}
@catch (NSException * e) 
{
UIAlertView *alt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:[e reason] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alt show];
[alt release];
return ;
    }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have the permission to upload for other accounts? `Also it is uploading fine with some accounts but facing issue with others.`

Comment: I have check all the permission  It working fine with all account first but someone who remove post that image.

Comment: then image will be hide from facebook wall                          Note : if any user post feed over facebook wall then it successfully over there .

Comment: @praveen when I am posting image over facebook wall ,if image successfully uplading then I will getting appid of posted image.

Comment: I am not able to get what you are trying to communicate. Do you mean to say once a user removes a posted image then it fails?

Comment: Yes, whenever I try out on first instance the image is getting posted.But when that user removes the image from his wall then (for some accounts), again when I try to post image though appid is image id is getting generated, image is not getting displayed over wall neither photo gallery.Feeds are getting displayed.Only images are not and that only for some accounts